# How to delete all user-defined commands starting with XYZ?

Tags: command-line, user-commands

How can I delete all user-defined commands where names share a common prefix (e.g. `XYZSomeCmd`, `XYZAnotherCmd`, ...)?

---

Found myself with a lot of dead commands while writing a plugin and changing prefix for commands. Wonder how to clean up without restarting Vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command:

```vim
for cmd in getcompletion("XYZ", "command") | execute "delcommand " . cmd | endfor
```

Version dependency:

```vim
for              " +v7.0031
getcompletion()  " +v7.4.2011
execute()        " +v7.0001
delcommand       " +v7.0001
```